# dummyuser creating users

Tags: mysql, security

I'm writing a script which weekly updates the users who have access to a database (all users from a specific group in our AD).

In my script I have to authenticate me as an user with the privileges to create users and to grant them privileges.

I dislike using the root user (and his plaintext password!) in a script, so I hope to create a dummyuser with as little as possible privileges, I want to reduce the security risk.

Is there a possible way and will it be secure? Which privileges will this dummyuser need?

Comment: Please add the script you are using/writing.

Answer (score 0):

create a user with grant option privilege.

GRANT [whatever privilege to that normal user] TO 'normal_user'@'ipaddress' WITH GRANT OPTION IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;